# How to connect Microsoft Access database in linux server?

Tags: php, ms-access, cpanel

I am using php and MS Access. In my local system its working fine.
How I can implement the same thing in server. I am using a Linux server. I have done lots of project with mysql database.This is the first time I am working php and MS Access.

Please give me a solution
Thank you

Comment: Do you intend to have the Access database serve as a back-end data store for a web application?

Comment: I don’t see any advantage or reason to use Access as the database. Any particular reason why you not using MySQL?

Comment: I have to connect to my client database. Client is having full database he is not sharing full database he given only few table that is only for my work

Comment: client is using ms access database